# PHP seems to be returning incorrect weekdays

Tags: php, date, datetime

First of all, here is my code:

```
<?php
$year = 1006;
while ($year <= 1996)
{
    $date = '1/26/' . $year;
    if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Monday')
    {
        echo $date . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $year += 10;
}
?>
```

This is supposed to output the January 26s between 1000 and 1999 where the year ends with a 6 and the date falls on a Monday. Here is the output:

```
1/26/1006
1/26/1096
1/26/1136
1/26/1186
1/26/1226
1/26/1316
1/26/1366
1/26/1406
1/26/1496
1/26/1536
1/26/1586
1/26/1626
1/26/1756
1/26/1846
1/26/1976
```

All seems well. However, when I look at few of these years on timeanddate.com, the weekdays do not seem to have anything in common:

[1/26/1006](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1006&country=1) falls on a Saturday

[1/26/1406](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1406&country=1) falls on a Tuesday

[1/26/1756](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1756&country=1) does fall on a Monday

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you running 32-bit PHP or 64-bit PHP? If 32-bit then the maximum supported year range is from about 1904 to 2032

Comment: Yep, I'm running 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` converts a string representation of a date into a unix timestamp - the number of seconds since jan 1, 1970.  You may start to see the problem here...

A timestamp is typically stored in a 32 bit integer, which gives a range between 1970 and 2038.  Trying to generate timestamps for dates outside that range will give you undefined behavior.

-- edit --

From the php manual:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from
>   01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

Comment: On most platforms, PHP use a 32-bit __signed__ integer, with -ve values being before 1970, giving 1904 as an earliest year; but you're right about the range being the OPs issue

Comment: @MarkBaker "on most platforms" doesn't cover for example windows and pre PHP 5.1, which is quite a common case. The range in that env starts from 1970.

Comment: @SamDufel You may want to add to this answer the ranges of timestamp in PHP. They are mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), in the changelog.

Comment: Cool! Didn't think of that - do you know offhand how I could get the weekday of dates before 1970?

Comment: @Joel - use DateTime objects to handle a much broader date range - but you'll still have issues with the missing days when countries switched from Julian to Gregorian

Comment: @eis - I do use "most" advisedly; but I'd hope that "most" people would be running a slightly more recent version of PHP, even on Windows - I'd certainly hope it isn't common

Comment: Hmm... Changing to `$date = new DateTime('1/26/' . $year); if ($date->format('l') == 'Monday')` does not change the output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As I said, you may have issues with the switch from Julian to Gregorian calendars - take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php - but you need PHP built with --enable-calendar to use these functions